# Profiling C/C++ code with Score-P and TAU

Tags: c++, c, profiling, trace, scorep

I am tying to profile a C/C++ code using Score-P. I have set a variable SCOREP_PROFILING_FORMAT to TAU_SNAPSHOT, to obtain TAU traces as it is explained here: https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/docs/old/bk05ch02s12.html).

The generated TAU folder contains several snapshot files like this:

```
$  ls
snapshot.0.0.0   snapshot.12.0.0  snapshot.2.0.0  snapshot.6.0.0
snapshot.1.0.0   snapshot.13.0.0  snapshot.3.0.0  snapshot.7.0.0
snapshot.10.0.0  snapshot.14.0.0  snapshot.4.0.0  snapshot.8.0.0
snapshot.11.0.0  snapshot.15.0.0  snapshot.5.0.0  snapshot.9.0.0
```

The problem arises when I try to analyze these files with pprof. If I run it I get:

```
$  pprof -f snapshot
Reading Profile files in snapshot.*
snapshot.ftab: No such file or directory
```

Opening one of these files shows that the format is XML:

```
 $  head -10 snapshot.0.0.0

 <profile_xml>
 <thread id="0.0.0.0" node="0" context="0" thread="0">
 </thread>

 <definitions thread="0.0.0.0">
 <metric id="0"><name>TIME</name>
 <units>ms</units>
 </metric>
 </definitions>
```

Also, I have tryied to change the TAU output format in the .bashrc file without success:

```
export TAU_PROFILE=1
export TAU_PROFILE_FORMAT="profile"
```

The OS, versions of installed programs, and building parameters are:

Ubuntu 12
Score-P 1.3
TAU 2.24
OpenMPI 1.6.5
Cube 4.2.3
Opari2 1.1.2
CUDA 7
gcc,g++ 4.6

To build Score-P I used:

```
./configure  --prefix=$scorep_prefix --with-cube=$cube_prefix \
             --with-opari2=$opari_prefix  \
             --with-cuda=$cuda_dir
```

To build TAU I used:

```
./configure -c++=g++ -cc=gcc -prefix=$tau_prefix -cuda=$cuda_dir
```

Everithing Built ran without errors.

Has anyone been in this same situation? If so, could you please give me some feedback on how to open these snapshot files?

Thank-you

Comment: Have you asked this question to score-p mailing list? If you already asked and got a working answer, please share it.

Comment: @Shibli I did not ask in the mailing list. In the end I stopped trying using TAU. My only work around was to use `cube` to visualise graphically the results. There was also a CLI command to do this, but not using those TAU files :- /